# Flutter Google Play Console Resource Name for Tests

Tags: dart, google-play, flutter, flutter-test

I developed an app in Flutter and I'm posting to Google Play, though, I would like to know how / where I can set the widget name information so that I can enter as login credentials on the Play Console for automated tests / captures (the image shows Google Play Location)...

[image: the image shows Google Play Location]

Comment: uau, nobody comment :(

Comment: No idea ? seems very important for better app quality ?

Comment: Still an open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16921

Comment: I was wondering if a widget key would be accessible by PlayStore reviewing process as in flutter integration tests.

Answer (score -3):

We cant use automated tests for now. But if you created an alpha version for pre-release test you can add login parameters:

1. Go to play console select your app
2. select "Pre-release report" in "version management" tab
3. in Settings tab fill "Login credential" section

pre-release testers will use it.

Answer (score -3):

Use this command:

`flutter build apk --release`

the apk will be generated, then you can publish it in Google Play.